# Why system call hooking produces different result everytime in Linux/Android 2.6.29?

Tags: android, c, linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

I have implemented system call hooking for `Android 2.6.29` kernel through a `LKM module`. I am tracing down one Android app for system calls. But interestingly, it returns different results every time I get a list of system calls.

I am not able to make bold text in the code section, so I have put ** to show where the difference starts.

For example,

first run:

```
our_sys_gettid ---> uid = 10028  
 our_sys_open ---> uid = 10028 with filename= /dev/cpuctl//tasks, flags= 131073, mode=0 
 our_sys_write ---> uid = 10028 with fd= 30, buf = 230 and count=3 
 our_sys_close ---> uid = 10028 with fd= 30  
 our_sys_setpriority ---> uid = 10028 with which= 0, who=230 and niceval=0 
 our_sys_futex ---> uid = 10028 with uadd=������, op=1, val=1, utime=<NULL>, uaddr2=������ and val3=  
 **our_sys_gettid ---> uid = 10028  
 our_sys_open ---> uid = 10028 with filename= /dev/cpuctl//tasks, flags= 131073, mode=0 
 our_sys_clock_gettime ---> uid = 10028 with which_clock=<NULL>, tp =   
 our_sys_clock_gettime ---> uid = 10028 with which_clock=<NULL>, tp =   
 our_sys_ioctl ---> uid = 10028 with fd=21, cmd=3222823425 and arg=3196467192 
 our_sys_ioctl ---> uid = 10028 with fd=21, cmd=3222823425 and arg=3196467192 **
 our_sys_clock_gettime ---> uid = 10028 with which_clock=<NULL>, tp =   
 our_sys_clock_gettime ---> uid = 10028 with which_clock=<NULL>, tp =   
 our_sys_ioctl ---> uid = 10028 with fd=21, cmd=3222823425 and arg=3196466496 
 our_sys_ioctl ---> uid = 10028 with fd=21, cmd=3222823425 and arg=3196466496 
 our_sys_dup ---> uid = 10028 with fildes=32 
 our_sys_close ---> uid = 10028 with fd= 32  
 .....................
```

Second run:

```
our_sys_gettid ---> uid = 10028  
 our_sys_open ---> uid = 10028 with filename= /dev/cpuctl//tasks, flags= 131073, mode=0 
 our_sys_write ---> uid = 10028 with fd= 30, buf = 228 and count=3 
 our_sys_close ---> uid = 10028 with fd= 30  
 our_sys_setpriority ---> uid = 10028 with which= 0, who=228 and niceval=0 
 our_sys_futex ---> uid = 10028 with uadd=������, op=1, val=1, utime=<NULL>, uaddr2=������ and val3=  
 **our_sys_gettid ---> uid = 10028  
 our_sys_open ---> uid = 10028 with filename= /dev/cpuctl//tasks, flags= 131073, mode=0 
 our_sys_write ---> uid = 10028 with fd= 30, buf = 228 and count=3 
 our_sys_clock_gettime ---> uid = 10028 with which_clock=<NULL>, tp =   
 our_sys_clock_gettime ---> uid = 10028 with which_clock=<NULL>, tp =   
 our_sys_ioctl ---> uid = 10028 with fd=21, cmd=3222823425 and arg=3198662648 
 our_sys_ioctl ---> uid = 10028 with fd=21, cmd=3222823425 and arg=3198662648 
 our_sys_clock_gettime ---> uid = 10028 with which_clock=<NULL>, tp =   
 our_sys_clock_gettime ---> uid = 10028 with which_clock=<NULL>, tp =   
 our_sys_ioctl ---> uid = 10028 with fd=21, cmd=3222823425 and arg=3198661952** 
 our_sys_close ---> uid = 10028 with fd= 30  
 our_sys_setpriority ---> uid = 10028 with which= 0, who=228 and niceval=0 
 our_sys_ioctl ---> uid = 10028 with fd=21, cmd=3222823425 and arg=1181359656 
 our_sys_ioctl ---> uid = 10028 with fd=21, cmd=3222823425 and arg=3198661952 
 our_sys_dup ---> uid = 10028 with fildes=32 
 our_sys_close ---> uid = 10028 with fd= 32  
 ....................
```

Third run:

```
our_sys_gettid ---> uid = 10028  
 our_sys_open ---> uid = 10028 with filename= /dev/cpuctl//tasks, flags= 131073, mode=0 
 our_sys_write ---> uid = 10028 with fd= 31, buf = 228 and count=3 
 our_sys_close ---> uid = 10028 with fd= 31  
 our_sys_setpriority ---> uid = 10028 with which= 0, who=228 and niceval=0 
 our_sys_futex ---> uid = 10028 with uadd=������, op=1, val=1, utime=<NULL>, uaddr2=������ and val3=X{�D  
 **our_sys_clock_gettime ---> uid = 10028 with which_clock=<NULL>, tp =   
 our_sys_clock_gettime ---> uid = 10028 with which_clock=<NULL>, tp =   
 our_sys_ioctl ---> uid = 10028 with fd=21, cmd=3222823425 and arg=3198035960 
 our_sys_ioctl ---> uid = 10028 with fd=21, cmd=3222823425 and arg=3198035960 
 our_sys_clock_gettime ---> uid = 10028 with which_clock=<NULL>, tp =   
 our_sys_clock_gettime ---> uid = 10028 with which_clock=<NULL>, tp =   
 our_sys_munmap ---> uid = 10028 with addr=1183178752 and len=770048 
 our_sys_close ---> uid = 10028 with fd= 32**  
 our_sys_ioctl ---> uid = 10028 with fd=21, cmd=3222823425 and arg=3198035264 
 our_sys_ioctl ---> uid = 10028 with fd=21, cmd=3222823425 and arg=3198035264 
 our_sys_dup ---> uid = 10028 with fildes=31 
 our_sys_close ---> uid = 10028 with fd= 31  
 ........................
```

Any idea why it's producing different results every time?

Is there any other better tool to trace system calls? I heard of `strace/ptrace`, `auditd` etc but not sure if they are usable for Android or not.

Comment: How do you separate output from the diffirent processes? Add a `pid` line to syscall trace info.

Comment: Looks like several threads playing around...

Comment: Expecting exactly the same behavior in a complex system may be a bit much.  strace/ptrace does work on Android, though you may need to build your own and will need to run as the same uid or as root.

Comment: Since each installed app on Android gets a unique uid but different pid every time we run it. So I have filtered above system calls for one app (uid=100028) which I am tracing down, ignoring the pid. I guess, in one run, pid will be the same and in second, it would be different. So could that be the reason to generate different set of sys calls?